# mysql query errors out with no-duplicate - but how to make it skip over the error and continue with execution of other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've following query:

```
$stmt_2 = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO connections (user_id, word_id, order_id, lang, created) VALUES (:user_id, :word_id, :order_id, :lang, :created)');

        $order_99 = 99;
        $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        foreach ($insert_id as $word_id) {
            $stmt_2->execute(array(
                ':user_id'  => $user_id,
                ':word_id'  => $word_id,
                ':order_id' => $order_99,
                ':lang'     => 'en',
                ':created'  => $now
            ));
            $order_99 ++;
        }

echo $stmt_2->rowCount(); // 1
```

I've setup DB for no duplicates. So this errors out when there are dups:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-108' for key 'No duplicates'
```

Problem is, not all array items in $insert_id are duplicates.

So I want execution to continue and not fail for non-duplicates. How would I do that? Surely there must be a mechanism for this?

Comment: Yes, simply `catch` the error

Comment: Put that query into a transaction and add set_foreign_key_checks=o.But constraints are there for a reason..

Comment: @Mihai I don't want to remove contraint, simply go past duplicates and insert non-dups from array.

Comment: @kingkero I do catch error. Maybe I formulated question in a bad way...

Comment: Maybe you did, maybe you did not. You will need a `try/catch` statement inside the `foreach` so it won't stop it from executing

Comment: Put a @ before execute to ignore the warnings.

Comment: @kingkero try/catch did it :) thanks! You can make it as answer if you wish.

Comment: @salivan Thanks for the feedback and glad I could help. If you used a specific Exception class, feel free to edit my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once you get an error your script will crash (and more importantly: the `foreach` loop will be broken out of). You can avoid this behaviour by [manually catching](http://www.php.net/manual/language.exceptions.php) the exception, e.g. like the following

```
foreach ($insert_id as $word_id) {
    try {
        $stmt_2->execute(array(
            ':user_id'  => $user_id,
            ':word_id'  => $word_id,
            ':order_id' => $order_99,
            ':lang'     => 'en',
            ':created'  => $now
        ));
        $order_99++;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```